# Select2 Autocomplete not able to select / tap on ios with cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, autocomplete, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I'm using select2 autocomplete plugin with Cordova / Phonegap, I have successfully integrated the plugin and autocomplete works perfectly fine in Android devices, However when I deploy the application in ios, it shows the suggestion list but I'm not able to tap/click on the suggestion provided.

Please Help!

Comment: Instead of touchstart event use click event and try the same.

Comment: @Mrunal: Thanks for replying, but can you please elaborate? I'm not manually adding click / tap events, my question is The Autocomplete List I'm not able to click / tap which is the default behaviour of select2

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2226

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mrunal it helped me to solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are few bug in Select2 regarding Autocomplete. You can find more details here:

https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2226

I would suggest to use "*Click*" event instead of "*TouchStart*" event.

Hope this helps.